# Angular 6 spinner component Router events not firing

Tags: angular

I have this spinner component which sits in the **App** component like this:

```
<pyb-spinner></pyb-spinner>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

It is designed to fire every time the route changes; my code looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription, of } from 'rxjs';

import { SpinnerService } from '../services/spinner.service';
import { switchMap, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'pyb-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.scss']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  loading: boolean;

  private spinnerSubscription: Subscription

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('hi');
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => {
          console.log(event);
          return event instanceof NavigationEnd
        }),
        map(() => {
          console.log(this.activatedRoute);
          return this.activatedRoute;
        }),
        map(route => { 
          console.log(route);
          return route.firstChild
        }),
        switchMap(route => route.data),
        map(data => {
          console.log(data);
        })
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.spinnerSubscription) this.spinnerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The only `console log` that is actually being hit is the first log in **ngOnInit** (`console.log('hi')`). All other logs are not being hit. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You haven't subscribed so you don't see anything occur

Comment: try https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Katana was right, I was not subscribing to anything.
This is what I ended up doing:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription, of } from 'rxjs';

import { SpinnerService } from '../services/spinner.service';
import { switchMap, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'pyb-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.scss']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  loading: boolean;

  private spinnerSubscription: Subscription

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => this.activatedRoute),
        map(route => route.firstChild),
        switchMap(route => route.data),
        switchMap(data => {
          console.log(data.disableSpinner);
          if (!data.disableSpinner)
            return this.spinnerService.onLoadingChanged
          else 
            return of(false);
        })
      ).subscribe(loading => this.loading = loading);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.spinnerSubscription) this.spinnerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to subscribe to NavigationEnd. i think this change may work.

```
pipe(
        router.events
            .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe(() => {
//  your logic

});
```